# (FATAL): The background process “SQL Databases and dependent apps” failed with a fatal error: The subprocess reported error number 127 when it ended

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-20.04, cpanel

I am installing CPanel in ubuntu 20.04.
But getting MySQL related error.

```
(FATAL): The background process “SQL Databases and dependent apps” failed with a fatal error: The subprocess reported error number 127 when it ended.
```

I searched in google for this error but did not any solutions.

How can I solve this issue?
Any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: Check the MySQL error logs. They should show you exactly what the fatal error is.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution.
Due to MySQL GPG key rotation this error was coming.
cpanel should update GPG key in there installation script.
To overcome this error before running installation script I import current MySQL GPG key manually then I run the installation script.
Command to import GPG key.

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys b7b3b788a8d3785c
```

Reference link - https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/19859355769495-New-cPanel-Installations-Fail-on-Ubuntu-due-to-MySQL-2023-Key-Expiry-and-Rotation?source=search&auth_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjo5Mjc3OTc5LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxOTk1NzMxODI0NDYzMSwidGlja2V0X2lkIjo5NTE3MTI0MywiY2hhbm5lbF9pZCI6NjMsInR5cGUiOiJTRUFSQ0giLCJleHAiOjE3MDU1OTc0Mjh9.FbMG0iezmDopNXFoo0VcFgLd2B-_YoywbljvgJjIw20

It worked like a charm.